# Change pointer on mouseover to Hand in Asp.net Chart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-charts

i am using Asp.net Chart and showing bar chart. 
i used dataPoint.MapAreaAttributes to call a JS func(which retrieves the ID) to show next chart on click of a particular bar in the existing chart.
but i am unable show hand pointer on mouse over the particular bar on the chart.
And when i use Datapoint.Url which is changing the mouse pointer to hand on mouseover the bar but i am unable to call the JS func.
So how to show Hand pointer on mouseover of a particular bar?

Answer (score 3):

`<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor='default'" />`

Comment: The value 'hand' did not work for me (don't really know why). I use the value 'pointer' which also displays a hand-cursor.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution (in VB.Net):

While creating your chart, iterate programmatically through all series data points, something like this:

```
While ...
   Dim oPoint as DataPoint = objSeries.Points(n)

   'add code for OnMouseMove and OnMouseOut events

   oPoint.MapAreaAttributes = "OnMouseOver=""document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';"""

   oPoint.MapAreaAttributes = oPoint.MapAreaAttributes &  "OnMouseOut=""document.body.style.cursor = 'default';"""

End While
```

Regards
M.R.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the mousepointer with CSS. apply the CSS on the bars and you'll have what you want

```
cursor:hand
```

there are all the options: http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. but where to place the class, in the series there is no cssclass property. when i placed css for the chart, the whole chart hand is implemented.

Comment: do you have an example how the HTML code looks for such a chart because i have no idea how it looks. what you could do is style the CSS hand with jquery selector. but that's not the best option

Comment: <style type="text/css">
.xlink {cursor:hand}
</style>
I have 2 Series, on mouseover of one series in the bar i need to show hand.
when i assign css-xlink in  <asp:Chart... hand is shown for the whole chart.
but for Series there is no property as CssClass to assign this css.

Comment: what is the html for the whole page? can you update your question with that?

Comment: <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
<asp:Chart ID="ClassPerformancechart" runat="server">        <Series>    <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartClass" ></asp:Series>
            <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartClass" > </asp:Series>
</Series>  
          <ChartAreas>
             <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartClass" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="true" >
                 <AxisY  Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Title="Score" ></AxisY>
                 <AxisX Title="Class" > </AxisX>
             </asp:ChartArea>
          </ChartAreas>         
        </asp:Chart>
         </td>       
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: i ment the HTML you get in the browser :) and edit your question so the html will be styled.

Comment: i got it.
i just added href to my code and it worked.
dataPoint.MapAreaAttributes = String.Format("onclick=""showClass({0})"" href=""#""""alt=""Show Report""", classid)
Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

The area tag is a bit funny -- cursor:hand and cursor:pointer in css don't work on it.  But you can use an href attribute to get the same effect.  Figure out the ID of the chart's containing element, then you can just use jquery, when the page is ready, to give the bar chart areas an empty href:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#YourChartElementID area[shape="rect"]').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
)};
```